# Sorting elements in a HashTable, Dictionary or such

Tags: c#, sorting, dictionary, hashtable

I have a set of data consisting of a name and associated content. Thus I'd go with something like `HashTable` or `Dictionary` to store those items.

I need to sort these data with two priorities. First they should be in an alphabetical order and then some items should be placed at the beginning in a specific order.

If alphabetical order would be my only requirement I'd use the `SortedDictionary`. This dictionary sorts the elements automatically based on the key.

What I'm looking for is a class which allows me to do:

1. Add elements in a random order
2. Sort all elements in an alphabetical order
3. Move (or remove and insert) elements to the beginning (or more generic: at any place I want to).

Comment: Could you in theory come up with a comparison method that will specify the order? If so, there are several collection classes that you could use (and I'll post a proper answer).

Comment: @MatthewWatson Well, yes and no. I had to implement the correct order of these specific elements into this comparison method. Not sure if this is a nice solution. It's possible to do so though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not look at `SortedList<TKey, TValue>`?

That should have appropriate functions to let you do what you want and it's fast for sorting!

Comment: Well, this collection does not have all appropriate functions but I implemented the comparison method to fit my needs. Accepted, since this approach is closest to what I was looking for, while all others answers are fine, too.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in collection that does what you need, but you can build your own relatively easily:

- Write an implementation of `IDictionary<TKey,TValue>`
- Put a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue> dict` and a `List<TKey> keys` inside
- When adding an element to `dict`, also add its key to `keys`
- When iteration is requested, iterate `keys` and then look up entries in the `dict`

If your collection is organized that way, you'd be able to re-order the keys independently of the dictionary entries. You need to be careful in the implementation because of double "bookkeeping" that should be going on in the operations that change the dictionary. Other than that, the solution should be relatively straightforward.

Comment: I hoped to avoid keeping keys twice. But I think this approach is a very sensible way to implement a neat solution.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide info if names of this data can be duplicated. Generally I think you can use a different ways to hold this data. You should remember that the essence of Dictonaries is hold key/value data where key is unique. The order of elements is not the essence of Dictionaries. This is more List matter in my opinion. So you, can try to mix Dictionary with the Linq to Objects. But maybe try to use Generic

```
    List< KeyValuePair< TKey, TValue>>.
```